# How to create a text formatter

Tags: formatting

I have this code

`.large
My First Document
.normal
.paragraph
This is my
.italics
very first
.regular
document, and I am very proud that I am getting this on the string. While this paragraph is not filled, the following one has automatic filling set:
.paragraph
.indent
.fill
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
.nofill
.outdent
Well, that was
.bold
exciting
.regular
good luck!`

and I need to be able to enter this and it executes the above commands (that start with .) and prints out the text then saves it to a PDF.

The commands are:
 - `.paragraph` Starts a new paragraph
 - `.fill` enables sets indentation to fill for paragrahs, where the last character of a line must
end at the end of the margin (except for the last line of a paragarph)
 - `.nofill` the default, sets the formatter to regular formatting
 - `.regular` resets the font to the normal font
 - `.italic` sets the font to italic
 - `.bold` sets the font to bold
 - `.indent` indents the text by a tab (or equivalent)
 - `.outdent` outdents the text by a tab (or equivalent)

Any idea how I'd go about this? Incredibly stuck at the moment.

Comment: i tried using js and creating methods that write a html file but i cant make the methods be read like how they're written in the aforementioned code

Comment: If you can post your tries that will be helpful for other people trying to help you.

Comment: that's just it tho, i don't know where to start myself